# how to build a edit module like evernote in android

Tags: android

I want to make an app that is similar to evernote. The main functions of the app is to write diary by which I can take pics, recording and small size videos. and store all those data using Parse. any suggestion on which android modules I should use and what need to be considered when I develop this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Wordpress-Android](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Android) which is the official Wordpress app for Android.

It can do some functions you previously stated such as writing text, putting some video, etc. And all these activities are associated with specific users. You also can get some logic from viewing their projects.

The [editor](https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-Editor-Android) has just been modularized. So you can easily reuse it in your project.